# como faço para imprir em ordem crecente um a cada clique

Tags: javascript

["C-1", "C-2", "C-3"], ["R-1","R-2", "R-3"], ["P-1","P-2", "P-3"] como faço para imprir em
ordem crecente e com prioridade um a cada clique exemplo :

senha com P vem em 1

senha com R vem em 2

senha com C vem em 3

alguem tem uma ideia dq fazer?

```js
const listaDeSenhaComum = [];
const listaDeSenhaRapida = [];
const listaDeSenhaPrioritaria = [];

let senhaComum = 1;

function gerarSenhaComum() {
  let senhaComumGerada = `C-${senhaComum++}`;
  listaDeSenhaComum.push(senhaComumGerada);
  console.log(listaDeSenhaComum);
}

let senhaRapida = 1;

function gerarSenhaRapida() {
  let senhaRapidaGerada = `R-${senhaRapida++}`;
  listaDeSenhaRapida.push(senhaRapidaGerada);
  console.log(listaDeSenhaRapida);
}

let senhaPrioritaria = 1;

function gerarSenhaPrioritaria() {
  let senhaPrioritariaGerada = `P-${senhaPrioritaria++}`;
  listaDeSenhaPrioritaria.push(senhaPrioritariaGerada);
  console.log(listaDeSenhaPrioritaria);
}
```

ai no html toda vez que pessoa clicar em chamar proxímo, imprimo em ordem de prioridade um a cada clicle.

Comment: as senhas R só devem ser impressas caso não exista ninguém na P, seguindo o mesmo para C e R?

Comment: isso exatamente isso

Comment: Ordenar listas é o menor dos problemas. As dúvidas são: Como que defini o tipo de senha que cada usuário receberá? Quantos são os caixas? Como vincula a senha aos caixas? Como define se um caixa está ou não livre? Cadê o código HTML que vai interagir com usuário?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta usar a função [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift), seguindo a ordem de prioridades, assim:

`listaDeSenhaPrioritaria.shift() || listaDeSenhaRapida.shift() || listaDeSenhaComum.shift()`

Caso algum dos arrays esteja vazio ele passa para o próximo.

exemplo completo:

```js
const listaDeSenhaComum = [ 'C-1', 'C-2', 'C-3' ];
const listaDeSenhaRapida = [ 'R-1', 'R-2', 'R-3' ];
const listaDeSenhaPrioritaria = ['P-1'];

function proximo(){
  return listaDeSenhaPrioritaria.shift() || listaDeSenhaRapida.shift() || listaDeSenhaComum.shift() || 'Vazio'
}

console.log(proximo());
console.log(proximo());
console.log(proximo());
console.log(proximo());
console.log(proximo());
console.log(proximo());
console.log(proximo());
console.log(proximo());

// P-1
// R-1
// R-2
// R-3
// C-1
// C-2
// C-3
// Vazio
```

basta chamar a função `proximo` no evento de clique da pagina

Comment: muito obrigado já estava sem ideia kkk